# Google Maps URL Scheme does not display marker

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I use `Google Maps URL Scheme` to open `Google Map` app on iOS, I have `schema`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=35.6653,139.6959&zoom=16&views=traffic&mapmode=standard"]];
```

But when I run application, the result does not show marker at location (35.6653,139.6959).

[image]

How to display marker?

Comment: use **q** instead of **center** 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?q=35.6653,139.6959&zoom=16&views=traffic&mapmode=standard"]];

Answer (score 12):

You Can Show Marker like as when you pass Latitude and Longitude in url like as

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.6653,139.6959"]];
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you have the method to open the Google Maps website or the Google Maps app with a marker on it.

```
- (void) onPositionPressed:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{
NSNumber * latitude = [sender.view associativeObjectForKey:@"latitude"];
NSNumber * longitude = [sender.view associativeObjectForKey:@"longitude"];

if(latitude && longitude){
    //Abrimos Google Maps...
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?q=%.6f,%.6f&center=%.6f,%.6f&zoom=15&views=traffic", [latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue], [latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue]]]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?&z=15&q=%.6f+%.6f&ll=%.6f+%.6f", [latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue], [latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue]]]];        }
}
}
```

In these case, latitude and longitude are NSNumbers but you could use normal double vars.

I hope this help anybody ;)

Comment: You can show marker, but the title will be not a title of string, but the coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly there is not way to show a marker using the URL scheme for Google Maps. You can just pass a parameter to show directions from your current location. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) is a list with all the supported parameters for the scheme.

Comment: I can't found any parameter support to show marker on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Comment: Yes, there is no way to show the marker as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need add param **q=lat,long**

Example:

```
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 21.0287747, longitude: 105.850176)
    let zoom = 15
    let trafficMode = "traffic" //(satellite, traffic, or transit)

    guard let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)&q=\(location.latitude),\(location.longitude)&zoom=\(zoom)&views=\(trafficMode)") else { return }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        // for iOS 10, below is deprecated
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
```